# maven release:prepare takes forever in azure pipeline

Tags: maven, azure-pipelines

When running maven goal release:prepare this step takes extremely long time or maybe even its stuck, dont know yet:

`[INFO] [prepare] 5/17 map-release-versions`

Snippet of yaml file:

```
        mavenPomFile: 'pom.xml'
        goals: 'release:prepare'
        options: '-s settings_lsl.xml'
```

Is there a way to speed this up?

Comment: Show us the log output

Comment: I solved it. I forgot to add the -B (interactive mode) flag. With -B flag it worked as it should. Not really sure why.  (Except that I also had to do an explicit checkout of my build branch so that im workin in a non-detached branch)

Comment: Would you please turn your comment into an answer and [mark it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235)? This will make it easier for people who have the same question to find answers.